# ARMv7 Word Patch (CBZ)

Tags: arm, disassembly

I'm disassembling an iPhone app

I'm trying to batch the instruction CBZ -> CBNZ

Instruction Code: **D9 09 00 34**

As per my understanding, CBZ will jump to the address if value of register is 0

I have tried to convert it to CBNZ **D9 09 00 35** but that didn't help

---

D9 09 00 34

00000000: 01000100 00111001 00100000 00110000 00111001 00100000  D9 09 
00000006: 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110100 00001010  00 34.

D9 09 00 35

00000000: 01000100 00111001 00100000 00110000 00111001 00100000  D9 09 
00000006: 00110000 00110000 00100000 00110011 00110101 00001010  00 35

I appreciate your support

Comment: CBZ is a 16 bit thumb instruction 0xD909.  please refer to the arm documentation.  If you want to change between CBZ and CBNZ then use the op bit in the instruction.

Comment: I'm still learning  ARM. Could you please add more details (patched version)?

Comment: infocenter.arm.com.  arm architecture then reference manuals then arm7-ar.  search for the word alphabetical to find the alphabetical list of instructions then look for CBZ

Comment: you cant possibly learn an instruction set without the documentation, esp if you plan to hack on the machine code.